# how to avoid hidden files when defining glob_wildcards (multiple) from input files

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I am trying to define the wildcards based on the input directory. Currently, my solution looks like this:

```
files = glob_wildcards("input/{organism}/{gene}/{sequence}.txt")
```

However, I noticed that the `input/` directory may contain hidden files or subfolders that start with `.` or `._`. I want to exclude them while defining wildcards.

I came across the concept of `constraining wildcards` in the documentation, but I am unsure how to apply them to my situation. I have attempted to use them, but the wildcards returned empty.

(regex: match not starting with `.`)

```
files = glob_wildcards("input/{organism,[^.]+}/{gene,[^.]+}/{sequence,[^.]+}.txt")


files:
Wildcards(organism=[], gene=[], sequence=[])
```

**EDIT**
My example output when not using regex:

```
files:
Wildcards(organism=['organism', 'organism'], 
          gene=['gene', 'gene'], 
          sequence=['._gene-pseudo_V:123..456__organism__gene', 'gene-pseudo_V:123..456__organism__gene']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but the regex you are using is incorrect:
Instead of e.g. `{gene,[^.]+}` you need to add something the remaining wildcard should match, e.g. `{gene,[^.][^/]+}` for all the wildcards which are supposed to exclude files with starting `.` (hidden files):

```py
files = glob_wildcards("input/{organism,[^.][^/]+}/{gene,[^.][^/]+}/{sequence,[^.][^/]+}.txt")
```

Normally I would add a leading `^` indicating the beginning of the string, however that seems to prevent `snakemake` from matching the file names, so the leading `^` is ommitted.

(tested, works locally against the file names you've provided)

edit: I've adapted suggestions from TroyComi. Also apparently `snakemake` doesn't like the beginning-of-string `^` indicator.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `.` in a character class; it is treated as literal in that context.  I'd also replace the last `.+` to match anything with `[^/]+`, e.g. not a file separator.  Matching everything will lead to lots of backtracking.  Overall, try `^[^.][^/]+`

Comment: I've tried both regexes proposed by @euronion and @Troy Comi but none of them worked. I still see `files:
Wildcards(organism=[], gene=[], sequence=[])`

Comment: @TroyComi Interesting, another learning, thanks!

Comment: @amk : Both TroyComi's and my regex work for me. Can you provide a list of example filenames which don't work for you?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version which works locally for me.